# Java Suppress Specific Annotation

Tags: java, maven, annotations

Context: I want to create an annotation which creates a compile-time error in a Production environment which is suppressed in a development environment. This annotation will be used on mock code to make sure it never gets from dev to production.

I've created the Annotation and Annotation Processor as a Maven project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>Fail-Annotation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Currently, the annotation itself is quite trivial

```
package com.fail.annotation;

public @interface Fail
{

    String value();
}
```

The processor is, similarly, simple

```
package com.fail.annotation;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"com.fail.annotation.Fail"})
public class FailProcessor extends AbstractProcessor
{

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> set, RoundEnvironment re)
    {
        for (Element e : re.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Fail.class))
        {
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(
                    Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                    "Forced Fail: " + e.getAnnotation(Fail.class).value(),
                    e
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When included as a dependency in a new project, the annotation works flawlessly.

```
package com.faildemo;

import com.fail.annotation.Fail;

public class FailHere
{

    @Fail("Mock Data")
    int userid = 1;
}
```

I can change the pom.xml in the demo project to disable annotation processors (-proc:none), but this won't work if we want to use other annotation processors in our project.

We can manually specify which processors to use with the maven annotationProcessors configuration field, but then we have to manually code each one, which will be tedious and error-prone in a large project, particularly with multiple profiles.

**TL;DR: Is there any way, in maven and/or javac arguments, to globally suppress a particular annotation or annotation processor?**

Comment: The output of `javac -help` includes the following:  "`-Akey[=value]` - Options to pass to annotation processors".  That sounds like what you want.  So maybe pass in something like `-Aenv=prod` [through your pom.xml file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html)?